# Returning object when expecting node

Tags: jquery

After some interaction in the table with id "myTable", I want to pass some nodes (bottom right of my table) to a function, myFunction. It gives the error, "parameter 1 is not of type 'node'".

I know `$(this)[0]` is giving me nodes, but when I add them to `theNodes` using `add()`, it gives an object.

```
$("#myTable").mouseup(function () {
    var theNodes = $();
    $("#myTable").find("tr:gt(2) td:gt(4)").each( function() {
       $(theNodes).add($(this)[0]);
    });  
    var result = myFunction($(theNodes));
});
```

It may be my declaration for `theNodes`, or using `add()`, but they were the only combinations I could use that didn't throw other errors.

How do I add nodes to theNodes where the result is node?

Answer (score 3):

You're **way** over-using `$()`, and ending up with a jQuery object (set) containing jQuery objects as a result. (Specifically: Calling `.add` and passing in a jQuery object rather than a DOM node or array ends up putting that jQuery object inside the jQuery object you're calling `add` on.)

To pass a jQuery set (a wrapper around the matching nodes) for those nodes, you simply do this:

```
$("#myTable").mouseup(function () {
    var result = myFunction($("#myTable").find("tr:gt(2) td:gt(4)"));
    // ...presumably use `result` here...
});
```

`myFunction` will receive a jQuery set, which will have the raw DOM elements at `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was overthinking it.